# How to inject a value to a sub-property of a bean (without annotations)?

Tags: jsf-2

I want to ask you if it is possible to inject a value to a sub-property of a bean.

This is what I want to do, but Eclipse IDE complains with:

*Bean property beanB.subprop not found on parent class paq.paq.BeanA*

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>beanA</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>paq.paq.BeanA</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>beanB.subprop</property-name>
            <value>Hello!</value>
        </managed-property>        
</managed-bean>



public class BeanA implements Serializable {

    public BeanB beanB = null;      

    public Skin getBeanB() {
        if (this.beanB == null) {
            this.beanB = new BeanB();
        }
        return this.beanB;
    }       

    public void setBeanB(BeanB beanB) {     
        this.beanB = beanB;
    }

}


public class BeanB implements Serializable {

    public String subprop = null;       

    public String getSubprop() {
        return this.subprop;
    }       

    public void setSubprop(String subprop) {        
        this.subprop = subprop;
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every nested bean needs to be declared as a managed bean as well. You need to inject it on the nested bean instead and then inject the nested bean itself in the main bean.

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>beanA</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>paq.paq.BeanA</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>beanB</property-name>
        <value>#{beanB}</value>
    </managed-property>        
</managed-bean>
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>beanB</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>paq.paq.BeanB</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>subprop</property-name>
        <value>Hello!</value>
    </managed-property>        
</managed-bean>
```